# How to run "ms-settings:network-wifisettings" hidden from VBScript?

Tags: windows, vbscript, windows-10

I am attempting to write a .vbs file that opens ms-settings:network-wifisettings, which is a specific page of the Windows 10 Settings App, completely hidden. It will simulate keystrokes and close the window on its own. The VBScript is executed from a .bat file.

My problem lies within making the ms-settings:network-wifisettings window hidden. I am aware of:

```
myObject.Visible = False
```

and

```
myObject.Run "ms-settings:network-wifisettings", 0
```

... But neither of these solutions seem to work for this particular application. It is strange, because I definitely accomplished this a few weeks ago but had my laptop stolen, and lost the script with it. So I know this must be possible somehow.

---

My current script is as follows:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.shell")
WshShell.Visible = False
WshShell.Run "ms-settings:network-wifisettings", 0

WshShell.AppActivate("Settings")
WshShell.sendKeys "%{F4}"
WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.AppActivate("Windows Security")
WshShell.sendKeys "[my username]"
WshShell.sendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.sendKeys "[my password]"
WshShell.sendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

---

*Note: the reason I am sending Alt+F4 to the first "Settings" window is that in my scenario, the "Settings" window automatically brings up another dialogue called "Windows Security." I would like to make both of these windows completely hidden for the duration of the script.*

Comment: Is the "Windows Security" dialog you describe a prompt for a wifi key?  Are you sure there's no API method to accomplish what you want?  [Does this page](http://superuser.com/q/133097/204705) give you any alternative solutions not involving this kludge of sending keystrokes?

Comment: Yes, it does.

Unfortunately this particular WLAN requires username and password. As far as I know, there is no way to export username along with the network profile. Correct me if I am wrong.